# java.util.properties getProperty method returns null for UTF-8 string

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a problem getting localized value (a UTF-8 string) from the properties file. 
Here is what i did ..

```
//properties file containing
//name=हिन्दी
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  File f = new File("path\\to\\properties\\file");
  Properties p = new Properties();
  try
   {
     p.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   }
  catch(IOException iox) {}
  System.out.println(p.getProperty("name")); //outputs null
  System.out.println(p.toString()); //outputs  { name= हिन्दी }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are passing the `Charset` to to `InputStreamReader`, rather than `FileInputStream`, right?

Comment: Consider iterating over the name-value pairs in the Properties and printing their contents, char at a time in hex. See if something funky is going on.

Comment: oh yeah! just a typo here.. in my actual code i passing <code>Charset</code> to InputStream

Comment: How the exception looks like? Can you print the stacktrace here please?

Comment: there is no exception, it just prints null

Comment: Side comment: Is your properties file correctly formmated? It must be encoded in iso-8859-1 (latin-1). And I suggest that the only chars in it be ascii-7 (only the first 128 chars of iso encodings and utf-8). When you need to encode non-ascii-7 chars you have to use: \uNNNN where NNNN is the four digits hexa of the Unicode codepoint of the char (use Character Map to find them). You can use (in Eclipse) the ResourceBundleEditor plugin to edit files visually.

Comment: @helios: since he's using the load() method that takes a Reader, the underlying properties file can be encoded in whatever he wants.

Comment: D'oh! your right @Michael. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the last line actually outputs `name= हिन्दी` then it looks like there's something wrong with the key String in the properties file; perhaps in includes some invisible whitespace character or one of the charaters of "name" is not the regular latin letter but something that looks like it. Take a look at the properties file in a hex editor.

Comment: Yes! the name is being appende with '/ufeff'.  but how and why is this happening? how to fix it!

Comment: I would manually edit the file. I don't know if it's generated by some software... in that case that software has a problem.

Comment: already tried manually editing the file. in np++ it(the extra char) can be seen only in hex view. The only way i am able to fix this is by changing the encoding of properties file itself. But then it would not be able to hold the UTF-8 strings.

Comment: @Naveed: that's an UTF-16(!) byte order mark. Whatever you're using to create that file is doing something very wrong there. A good text editor should have an option to save text as UTF-8 without any byte order mark. Np++ does have that option in the "Encoding" menu, but it may not get rid of an outright wrong BOM

Comment: @Naveed: oh, and if your preferred editor insists on using a BOM, a workaround might be to start the file with an empty line.

Comment: Fixed! just saved the properties file with UTF-8 Without BOM using np++. That was it. Thanks a lot for your time & help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`catch(IOException iox) {}`

this is called "mutual failure". Never do this. Your code that loads properties from file fails and throws exception and you even do not know about this. Add `e.printStackTrace()` and move code that prints properties values into the `try/catch` block. See the exception and fix the bug. I believe that your file path is wrong, so you will get `FileNotFoundException` or probably you do not have access rights to this file.

Comment: But in that case the last line would not output anything.